# Apple Movie Player sample resize

Tags: iphone

I'm using [Movie Player](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) to see video streaming in my ipod. But the video is always bigger than the screen. How I can resize the video view? I have tried to put frame size in a lot of places, but without sucess..

I appreciate all of tips and helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController * moviePlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:Video URL String];
moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
moviePlayerVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 300);
moviePlayerVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerVC.view];
```

Comment: Ok, but in which file I put this? I'm using the sample Movie Player, from Apple.

Comment: video url string means ,, Complete Path From Where You Fetch Video